# add lines into style.css

Tags: html, css, bash

So I want to create 200 pages in my site and for that I want to add few lines in style.css . I want to add below lines at end of the file

```
.wordpress
        width: 100%
        position: relative
        font-size: 22px
        color: #1a1a1a
        font-weight: 600
        min-height: 297px
        line-height: 22px
        background: url(../images/wordpress.png) no-repeat left top
```

I want to replace filename using script . Can someone guide me how can I do it ? I tried below tricks but it dindt work

```
for i in $(cat list1.txt) ; do echo  .$i{\ width: 100%;\ position: relative;\ font-size: 22px;\ color: #1a1a1a;\        font-weight: 600;\ min-height: 297px;\ line-height: 22px;\ background: url(../images/$i.png) no-repeat left top;\} >>  list3.txt ; done
```

Is there any other way to do this ? I have all the filenames in list1.txt file

Comment: do you want to change list3.txt with a filename from list1.txt ? or you want to  change a css class name with a filename?

Comment: Hello in list1.txt file I have filenames lilke wordpress.png joomla.png magento.png I want to add those in list3.txt

Comment: i have copied style.css to list3.txt . if this script work, I will update style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit. Now it should work:

```
for i in $(cat list1.txt) ; do 
    echo  ".$i{ 
        width: 100%; 
        position: relative; 
        font-size: 22px; 
        color: #1a1a1a;        
        font-weight: 600; 
        min-height: 297px; 
        line-height: 22px; 
        background: url(../images/$i.png) no-repeat left top;
        }" >>  list3.txt ; done;
```

You should have list1.txt like this:

```
wordpress
joomla
```

(separeted by new line and without .png)